# Swift Reload state button from plist

Tags: swift, ios8

I save the state button in an Dictionary on my plist in this mode 
i set the sender of my button

```
    func Button(sender: AnyObject) {

    if (stateButton == false) {

        self.addNameSenderButton("stateButton")
        stateButton = true
     }
    else
    {
        stateButton = false
     }
```

and then for reload the state

```
func reload () {

    let path = loadPath()
    //Retrieve contents from file at specified path
    var data = NSMutableDictionary(contentsOfFile: path)

    var dataSenderButton = data!["senderButton"] as Dictionary<String, AnyObject>

    for ( key) in dataSenderButton.keys {

      "\(key)" == true
     }}
```

but this not change the state of stateButton

I need to associate the dictionary key to var stateButton: Bool

how can I do to change the state ?

Comment: Where do you change the state? No wonder it does not change.

Comment: You should use NSUserDefaults

Comment: Is it a button or a switch?

Comment: I will show you how you can save them using useDefaults

Comment: Why NSUserDefault i not plist ?

Comment: actually user defaults is a plist but you don't have to deal with it

Comment: save is easy I am thinking how to load them programaticaly

Comment: When  saving you can use sender. whatever to identify your button but when loading you don't even have this option

Comment: using outlets I can reload them but without it I still don't know how it can be done

Comment: everything I already know that it works because if I use for example in function reload
stateButton = true ...
but I have to take statebutton from plist because I do not know which are chosen my user

Comment: Thats is easy to take care off I already implemented how to save here and only the ones that have changed its value

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71532/discussion-between-stack-and-leonardo-savio-dabus).

Answer (score 0):

Your code line

```
 "\(key)" == true
```

is a unused comparison. If you want to set the state of a button use

```
button.state = NSOnState
```

or

```
button.state = NSOffState
```

(where from your code it can't be seen how your button is actually called)

Comment: i have 100 button (add programmatically) i need to save the statebutton in a plist and then reload ( i used one stateButton this is just to simplify)

Comment: Yes. But from your code I can't see where you actually store the buttons.

Comment: I need to associate the dictionary key to stateButton: Bool

Comment: Like I have already said if you have an IBOutlet for each I can post the answer

Comment: If i want use NSUserDefaul ?